# How to match an expression using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a file of dictionary, here is a part of it:

```
amends
    [m0][b]{{MAINENTRY}}amends{{/MAINENTRY}}[/b] [p]UK[/p] [s]zzz_uk_B_B01_B0107_B0107310.wav[/s] [c teal]\[{{PRON}}əˈmendz{{/PRON}}\][/c] [p]US[/p] [s]zzz_us_A_A01_A0107_A0107310.wav[/s] [c orange]{{PART-OF-SPEECH}}noun{{/PART-OF-SPEECH}}[/c]
    {{Phrase}}[m3][c darkslategray][u]Phrase:[/u][/c] <<make amends>>{{/Phrase}}
amenity
    [m0][b]{{MAINENTRY}}amenity{{/MAINENTRY}}[/b] [p]UK[/p] [s]zzz_uk_B_B01_B0107_B0107410.wav[/s] [c teal]\[{{PRON}}əˈmiːnəti{{/PRON}}\][/c] [p]US[/p] [s]zzz_us_A_A01_A0107_A0107410.wav[/s] [c teal]\[{{PRON}}əˈmenəti{{/PRON}}\][/c] [c orange]{{PART-OF-SPEECH}}noun{{/PART-OF-SPEECH}}[/c] [c sienna]{{SYNTAX-CODING}}\[countable\]{{/SYNTAX-CODING}}[/c] [c orangered]{{RESTRICTION-CLASS}}usually plural{{/RESTRICTION-CLASS}}[/c] {{INFLECTION}}[c rosybrown]\[[/c][c rosybrown][i]{{INFLECTION-TYPE}}singular{{/INFLECTION-TYPE}}[/i][/c] [c darkslategray]{{INFLECTION-ENTRY}}amenity{{/INFLECTION-ENTRY}}[/c] [c rosybrown][i]{{INFLECTION-TYPE}}plural{{/INFLECTION-TYPE}}[/i][/c] [c darkslategray]{{INFLECTION-ENTRY}}amenities{{/INFLECTION-ENTRY}}[/c][c rosybrown]\][/c]{{/INFLECTION}}
    [m1]{{DEFINITION}}something that makes it comfortable or enjoyable to live or work somewhere{{/DEFINITION}}
    [m3][ex][*]{{EXAMPLE}}Amenities include a gym, a pool, and a jacuzzi.{{/EXAMPLE}}[/*][/ex]
    [m3][ex][*]{{EXAMPLE}}parks, shops, and other local amenities{{/EXAMPLE}}[/*][/ex]
    {{Thesaurus}}[m3][c darkslategray][u]Thesaurus:[/u][/c] [ref dict="Macmillan English Thesaurus (En-En)"]things that make life easier or more comfortable[/ref][sub][c rosybrown]synonym[/c][/sub] {{/Thesaurus}}
amenorrhoea
    [m0][b]{{MAINENTRY}}amenorrhoea{{/MAINENTRY}}[/b] [p]UK[/p] [s]zzz_uk_B_B_1_B_142_B-142644-amenorrhoea.wav[/s] [c teal]\[{{PRON}}ˌeɪmenəˈriə{{/PRON}}\][/c] [p]US[/p] [s]zzz_us_A_A_1_A_158_A-158741-amenorrhoea.wav[/s] [c orange]{{PART-OF-SPEECH}}noun{{/PART-OF-SPEECH}}[/c] [c sienna]{{SYNTAX-CODING}}\[uncountable\]{{/SYNTAX-CODING}}[/c] [c darkgreen]{{SUBJECT-AREA}}medical{{/SUBJECT-AREA}}[/c]
    [m1]{{DEFINITION}}a medical condition in which a woman who is not pregnant does not{{/DEFINITION}} [i]{{NDV}}menstruate{{/NDV}}[/i] {{DEFINITION}}{{/DEFINITION}} [c darkslategray](={{GL}}produce a flow of blood once a month{{/GL}})[/c]
    {{Thesaurus}}[m3][c darkslategray][u]Thesaurus:[/u][/c] [ref dict="Macmillan English Thesaurus (En-En)"]menstruation and the menstrual cycle[/ref][sub][c rosybrown]hyponym[/c][/sub] [ref dict="Macmillan English Thesaurus (En-En)"]specific medical conditions[/ref][sub][c rosybrown]hyponym[/c][/sub] {{/Thesaurus}}
americano
    [m0][b]{{MAINENTRY}}americano{{/MAINENTRY}}[/b] [p]UK[/p] [s]zzz_uk_B_B43_B4343_B4343010.wav[/s] [c teal]\[{{PRON}}əˌmerɪˈkɑːnəʊ{{/PRON}}\][/c] [p]US[/p] [s]zzz_us_A_A43_A4343_A4343010.wav[/s] [c teal]\[{{PRON}}əˌmerɪˈkɑnoʊ{{/PRON}}\][/c] [c orange]{{PART-OF-SPEECH}}noun{{/PART-OF-SPEECH}}[/c] [c sienna]{{SYNTAX-CODING}}\[countable\]{{/SYNTAX-CODING}}[/c] {{INFLECTION}}[c rosybrown]\[[/c][c rosybrown][i]{{INFLECTION-TYPE}}singular{{/INFLECTION-TYPE}}[/i][/c] [c darkslategray]{{INFLECTION-ENTRY}}americano{{/INFLECTION-ENTRY}}[/c] [c rosybrown][i]{{INFLECTION-TYPE}}plural{{/INFLECTION-TYPE}}[/i][/c] [c darkslategray]{{INFLECTION-ENTRY}}americanos{{/INFLECTION-ENTRY}}[/c][c rosybrown]\][/c]{{/INFLECTION}}
    [m1]{{DEFINITION}}a cup of coffee made by pouring a little{{/DEFINITION}} [i]{{NDV}}espresso{{/NDV}}[/i] {{DEFINITION}}{{/DEFINITION}} [c darkslategray](={{GL}}strong Italian coffee{{/GL}})[/c] {{DEFINITION}}on top of hot water{{/DEFINITION}}
    {{Thesaurus}}[m3][c darkslategray][u]Thesaurus:[/u][/c] [ref dict="Macmillan English Thesaurus (En-En)"]non-alcoholic drinks[/ref][sub][c rosybrown]hyponym[/c][/sub] [ref dict="Macmillan English Thesaurus (En-En)"]general words for drinks[/ref][sub][c rosybrown]synonym[/c][/sub] {{/Thesaurus}}
amethyst
    [m0][b][c darkmagenta]▪ [u]I.[/u][/c][/b] [b]{{MAINENTRY}}amethyst{{/MAINENTRY}}[/b] [sup]{{HOMO-NUM}}1{{/HOMO-NUM}}[/sup] [p]UK[/p] [s]zzz_uk_B_B01_B0108_B0108610.wav[/s] [c teal]\[{{PRON}}ˈæməθɪst{{/PRON}}\][/c] [p]US[/p] [s]zzz_us_A_A01_A0108_A0108610.wav[/s] [c orange]{{PART-OF-SPEECH}}noun{{/PART-OF-SPEECH}}[/c] [c sienna]{{SYNTAX-CODING}}\[countable/uncountable\]{{/SYNTAX-CODING}}[/c] {{INFLECTION}}[c rosybrown]\[[/c][c rosybrown][i]{{INFLECTION-TYPE}}singular{{/INFLECTION-TYPE}}[/i][/c] [c darkslategray]{{INFLECTION-ENTRY}}amethyst{{/INFLECTION-ENTRY}}[/c] [c rosybrown][i]{{INFLECTION-TYPE}}plural{{/INFLECTION-TYPE}}[/i][/c] [c darkslategray]{{INFLECTION-ENTRY}}amethysts{{/INFLECTION-ENTRY}}[/c][c rosybrown]\][/c]{{/INFLECTION}}
    [m2]{{DEFINITION}}a valuable purple stone that is used in jewellery{{/DEFINITION}}
    {{Thesaurus}}[m4][c darkslategray][u]Thesaurus:[/u][/c] [ref dict="Macmillan English Thesaurus (En-En)"]stones used in jewellery[/ref][sub][c rosybrown]hyponym[/c][/sub] {{/Thesaurus}}
    [m0]    [m0][b][c darkmagenta]▪ [u]II.[/u][/c][/b] [b]{{MAINENTRY}}amethyst{{/MAINENTRY}}[/b] [sup]{{HOMO-NUM}}2{{/HOMO-NUM}}[/sup] [p]UK[/p] [s]zzz_uk_B_B01_B0108_B0108620.wav[/s] [c teal]\[{{PRON}}ˈæməθɪst{{/PRON}}\][/c] [p]US[/p] [s]zzz_us_A_A01_A0108_A0108620.wav[/s] [c orange]{{PART-OF-SPEECH}}adjective{{/PART-OF-SPEECH}}[/c]
    [m2]{{DEFINITION}}light purple{{/DEFINITION}}
    {{Thesaurus}}[m4][c darkslategray][u]Thesaurus:[/u][/c] [ref dict="Macmillan English Thesaurus (En-En)"]words used to describe specific colours[/ref][sub][c rosybrown]hyponym[/c][/sub] {{/Thesaurus}}
```

I need by a given word to extract a part of dictionary page using regex. For example, input of word "amenity" should return:

```
 amenity
    [m0][b]{{MAINENTRY}}amenity{{/MAINENTRY}}[/b] [p]UK[/p] [s]zzz_uk_B_B01_B0107_B0107410.wav[/s] [c teal]\[{{PRON}}əˈmiːnəti{{/PRON}}\][/c] [p]US[/p] [s]zzz_us_A_A01_A0107_A0107410.wav[/s] [c teal]\[{{PRON}}əˈmenəti{{/PRON}}\][/c] [c orange]{{PART-OF-SPEECH}}noun{{/PART-OF-SPEECH}}[/c] [c sienna]{{SYNTAX-CODING}}\[countable\]{{/SYNTAX-CODING}}[/c] [c orangered]{{RESTRICTION-CLASS}}usually plural{{/RESTRICTION-CLASS}}[/c] {{INFLECTION}}[c rosybrown]\[[/c][c rosybrown][i]{{INFLECTION-TYPE}}singular{{/INFLECTION-TYPE}}[/i][/c] [c darkslategray]{{INFLECTION-ENTRY}}amenity{{/INFLECTION-ENTRY}}[/c] [c rosybrown][i]{{INFLECTION-TYPE}}plural{{/INFLECTION-TYPE}}[/i][/c] [c darkslategray]{{INFLECTION-ENTRY}}amenities{{/INFLECTION-ENTRY}}[/c][c rosybrown]\][/c]{{/INFLECTION}}
    [m1]{{DEFINITION}}something that makes it comfortable or enjoyable to live or work somewhere{{/DEFINITION}}
    [m3][ex][*]{{EXAMPLE}}Amenities include a gym, a pool, and a jacuzzi.{{/EXAMPLE}}[/*][/ex]
    [m3][ex][*]{{EXAMPLE}}parks, shops, and other local amenities{{/EXAMPLE}}[/*][/ex]
    {{Thesaurus}}[m3][c darkslategray][u]Thesaurus:[/u][/c] [ref dict="Macmillan English Thesaurus (En-En)"]things that make life easier or more comfortable[/ref][sub][c rosybrown]synonym[/c][/sub] {{/Thesaurus}}
```

But the problem is I can't even match the single "amenity" at the beginning. I tried:

```
try (var t = new Scanner(Path.of("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\temp.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        Stream<MatchResult> res = t.findAll(Pattern.compile("^amenity$"));
        res.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.group()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

And the resulting stream is empty

Question:

1. How to match single "amenity" at the beginning of expected result
2. How to match the whole page by given word

Comment: @Carapace but then program finds 3 entries of "amenity", whereas I need the one in the beginning. Anyway, why is it not working with Scanner, but alright to use this regex in other classes and it works correctly

Comment: @user16320675 it must be Scanner AND using regex. Why is it not working with Scanner, but alright to use this regex in other structures (I tried regex online and it works)

Comment: @user16320675 Okay, then the way you described is the best option for the task?
I am asking because dictionary contains approximately 500 thousands lines and to find for example 10 words you need to traverse 10 times. But if I use regex, I can combine these 10 words using "|" and therefore it will be sufficient to go through the dictionary only 1 time

Comment: @user16320675 thank you, I'll try to develop the solution and in case I have questions I'll rewrite the post correctly

Comment: @user16320675 thanks, I did just the same way, checking for 10 words in one traversing!